# How do I make aliases in Sitecore inherit children?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

If I alias some content, I'd like all child content to become children of that alias as well.

Ex:

```
- home
    - info
        -client1
            -blog        <-= create alias to this level
                -2015
                    -July
                        -Some-Title-of-a-Blog-Entry
```

I'd like to create the alias "/blogs/client1" on "/info/client1/blog", and then have all children continue to resolve under the aliased address as so:

```
- home
    -blogs
        -client1    <-= this is the actual alias
            -2015
                -July
                    -Some-Title-of-a-Blog-Entry
```

So in effect, I'd like "/blogs/client1/2015/July/Some-Title-of-a-Blog-Entry" to resolve to the content "/info/client1/blog/2015/July/Some-Title-of-a-Blog-Entry"

Is Sitecore able to do this out of the box?  Is there a quick pipeline solution that I'd have to create, or has this been done already?

Comment: It's not possible out of the box, you would have to override the `LinkProvider` and provide your implementation similar to [this](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/11/link-management-with-sitecore.aspx) or [this](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/02/yalp-yet-another-link-provider-for-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx) but those only work on the item itself and not the children so the code would need to be extended (which may have performance impacts)

Comment: As jammykam mentioned above, that is not possible out of box and isn't intended aliases functionality at all. What you can do to instead is use sort of reverse proxy. You can even make IIS work as RP - here is my blog post how to do that: http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/iis-url-rewrite-and-sitecore-instance however minв performance overhead for IIS

Comment: What these guys said. Single page vanity URL = Sitecore alias. Large scale URL changing = IIS URL Rewrite.

Comment: What about using a proxy?  http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.com/2014/09/sitecore-proxies-and-clones.html